# Convert UTF8 apostrophe and quotes to ASCII for VB6 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encoding, character-encoding

I have a VB6 desktop app and iOS and Android smartphone apps. When someone enters a name such as O'Hara in the iOS app it comes through to the VB6 desktop app as unreadable characters. I assume this is a UTF8 to ASCII conversion issue? I would like to intercept this data server side and change the ' and " to the proper character that will read properly in VB6. How should I do this in C# .NET?

Comment: VB4/5/6 use Unicode just fine (except as source code). What's the problem? [Edit] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the problematic characters with a version that fits in the character set used by VB 6:

```cs
string value = "The problem string";

value = value.Replace("\u2022", "-");
value = value.Replace("\u2013", "-");
value = value.Replace("\u2014", "-");
value = value.Replace("\u2015", "-");
value = value.Replace("\u2017", "_");
value = value.Replace("\u2018", "'");
value = value.Replace("\u2019", "'");
value = value.Replace("\u201a", ",");
value = value.Replace("\u201b", "'");
value = value.Replace("\u201c", "\"");
value = value.Replace("\u201d", "\"");
value = value.Replace("\u201e", "\"");
value = value.Replace("\u2026", "...");
value = value.Replace("\u2032", "'");
value = value.Replace("\u2033", "\"");
```

This is not an exhaustive list of all Unicode characters, of course.  You may end up finding you need to replace more, or alarm on them in some way.

Comment: The character set used by VB4/5/6 is Unicode. It's designed for Windows GUI applications, after all.

Comment: Internally VB6 uses Unicode, but for display, it's more complicated.  [https://www.example-code.com/vb/vbUnicode1.asp](This article) goes into more details.  It is why pre .NET VB developers tended to shy away from using anything outside of ASCII, even if it is possible.

Comment: Nice reference. I wonder if it would be simpler to SendMessageW WM_SetText (but I'm not going scare up VB6 to try it).